# Is there a good way to prevent jQuery from being redefined?

Tags: javascript, include-guards

I encountered a problem that took me some time to debug where a plug-in that I was using for jQuery (in this case jFeed) was not working. The problem ended up being because we also used [Amazon Associates product previews](https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/associates/tips/t8). The product previews code ends up including a number of other JS files through document.write(), including another copy of jQuery. Because the product previews code appeared below the jFeed script, jQuery was redefined without the getFeed function.

Is there a best practice to ensure that certain objects like jQuery only get defined once on a page? I'm thinking of something like #ifndef with C/C++, but I don't know how it would work in this case where I didn't write the code that dynamically pulled in jQuery again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think in your situation, it would probably be best to redefine the jQuery variable as something else. The other jQuery code might use a different version so you might want to define a new variable which would indicate which jQuery you're using.

You could so something like this:

```
 <script>
    var $jMain = jQuery;
 </script>
```

You would then just use the `$jMain` instead of `jQuery` or `$`. It'll be up to you to you to ensure you have the correct jQuery object when you do this. Here's the [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries#Referencing_Magic_-_Shortcuts_for_jQuery).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the environment inside one JS sandbox (like within a window or frame of a browser) was not really designed to support the modern world of pulling in scripts from various places; there's no way you can say "define this object and make it resistant to redefinition". (You can even redefine most of the Javascript built-ins if you try!)

Your best shot is to make sure that your code is eval'd last, which gives you final say over the state of the environment when it runs. That doesn't mean other code can't come along later and clobber your definitions, but that's generally really bad form. You can do this by having your script tag be the last element in the body of the document, for example.

See also this jQuery method, which won't help you directly, but gets you thinking about some solutions to page sharing: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/